# Error DNS server bind?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

**THIS IS MY File: /var/named/example.com.zone**

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     dns1.example.com.       hostmaster.example.com. (
            2001062501 ;serial
            21600   ;refresh after 6 hours
            3600    ;retry after 1 hour
            604800  ;expire after 1 week
            86400 ) ;minimum TTL 1 day

        IN      NS      dsn1.example.com.
        IN      MX      10      mail.example.com
        IN      A       192.168.0.104
dns         IN      A       192.168.0.104

machine6        IN      A       192.168.0.104
ftp     IN      A       192.168.0.104
mail    IN      CNAME   machine6
www     IN      CNAME   machine6
```

**THIS IS MY File: /var/named/example.com.rr.zone**

```
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     dns1.example.com.       hostmaster.example.com. (
        2001062501 ;serial
        21600   ;refresh after 6 hours
        3600    ;retry after 1 hour
        604800  ;expire after 1 week
        86400 ) ;minimum TTL 1 day

@       IN      NS      machine6.example.com.
1       IN      PTR     machine6.example.com.
2       IN      PTR     machine6.example.com.
3       IN      PTR     machine6.example.com.
4       IN      PTR     machine6.example.com.
```

**THIS IS MY File: /etc/named.conf**

```
    zone "example.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "example.com.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "example.com.rr.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

**BUT WHEN I ISSUED # service named restart**

```
    Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
    Starting named:
    Error in named configuration:
    zone example.com/IN: NS 'dsn1.example.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
    zone example.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
    _default/example.com/IN: bad zone
    example.com.rr.zone:3: SOA record not at top of zone (104.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file example.com.rr.zone failed: not at top of zone
    zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
    _default/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not at top of zone
    zone mydomain.com/IN: loaded serial 2013042201
    zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
    zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
    zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
    zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
    zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your forward zone file, see error in the following line:

```
zone example.com/IN: NS 'dsn1.example.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
```

You specify your **NS Record** as `dns1.example.com.` but the **A Record** is `dns.example.com`

Correct zone file example:

```
$TTL    86400
@               IN      SOA     dns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                        2001062501
                        21600
                        3600
                        604800
                        86400
                        )
; NS RECORD
@               IN      NS              dns1
; MX RECORD
@               IN      MX      10      mail
; A RECORDS
@               IN      A               192.168.0.104
dns1            IN      A               192.168.0.104
mail            IN      A               192.168.0.104
machine6        IN      A               192.168.0.104
ftp             IN      A               192.168.0.104
; CNAME RECORDS
www             IN      CNAME           example.com.
```

The **MX Record** must point to an **A Record**, not a **CNAME Record**.

This example will also define `example.com` as a valid domain name in the first **A Record**.

`machine6` and `ftp` can also be a **CNAME Record**.

Comment: it somehow worked, but then when i tried to issue # nslookup mail.example.com the result will come out like this ** server can't find mail.example.com: NXDOMAIN